# PostgreSQL 9.5 Replication Lag running on EC2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postgresql-9.5

I have a series of PostgreSQL 9.5 servers running on `r4.16xlarge` instances and Amazon Linux 1 that started experiencing replication lag of several seconds starting this week.  The configurations were changed but the old configs weren't saved so I'm not sure what the previous settings were.  Here's the custom values:

```
max_connections = 1500
shared_buffers = 128GB
effective_cache_size = 132GB
maintenance_work_mem = 128MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
#effective_io_concurrency = 10
work_mem = 128MB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
max_worker_processes = 64
synchronous_commit = off
```

The drive layout is as follows - 4 disks for the xlog drive and 10 for the regular partition, all `gp2` disk type.

```
Personalities : [raid0]
md126 : active raid0 xvdo[3] xvdn[2] xvdm[1] xvdl[0]
      419428352 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

md127 : active raid0 xvdk[9] xvdj[8] xvdi[7] xvdh[6] xvdg[5] xvdf[4] xvde[3] xvdd[2] xvdc[1] xvdb[0]
      2097146880 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
```

The master server is a smaller `c4.8xlarge` instance with this setup:

```
max_connections = 1500
shared_buffers = 15GB
effective_cache_size = 45GB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 16
work_mem = 26MB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
max_worker_processes = 36
```

With this drive layout:

```
Personalities : [raid0]
md126 : active raid0 xvdd[2] xvdc[1] xvdb[0] xvde[3]
      419428352 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

md127 : active raid0 xvdr[12] xvdg[1] xvdo[9] xvdl[6] xvdh[2] xvdf[0] xvdp[10] xvdu[15] xvdm[7] xvdj[4] xvdn[8] xvdk[5] xvdi[3] xvds[13] xvdt[14] xvdq[11]
      3355435008 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
```

I guess I'm looking for optimal settings for these two instance types so I can eliminate the replication lag.  None of the servers are what I would call heavily loaded.

Comment: Could be a lame network, could be a replication conflict.

Answer (score 0):

With further digging I found that the following setting fixed the replication lag:

```
hot_standby_feedback = on
```

This may cause some WAL bloating on the master but now the backlog is gone.